# button to add event in calendar

Tags: android, calendar

In my app i have a calendar function wherein i have a button in layout file and on click i want it to directly add predefined 3 day full day appointment event in default calender. i ave following java code can anyone guide what else i need to add to get it working...

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                cal.set(year, mnth, day, hrs, min);
                long beginTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

                cal.set(year, mnth, day, hrs, min);
                long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
                intent.putExtra("allDay", true);

                intent.putExtra("endTime",
                        cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
                intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
...
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, cal.getTimeInMillis());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, cal.getTimeInMillis());
...
```